# Safe way to remove an outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

We recently removed a wet bar from our living room and we're going to replace it with a kegerator. On the wall above the wet bar, there are currently two switches and one outlet, but not in a row; one of the switches is above the outlet and the other switch. We want to have an outlet down low so the plug for the kegerator is not visible.

Surprise surprise, when the plumber opened up the wall to cap off the plumbing, he uncovered a capped off outlet box (which while trying to find out how to deal with our situation I've learned shouldn't have been dry walled over). So putting a new outlet in there seems straightforward enough.

My question has to do with the switches and outlet higher up on the wall. Ideally, we'd like to not have an outlet there at all, and just have the two switches next to each other. But as I've mentioned, I know I shouldn't drywall over where the outlet was.Can I move the upper switch to be next to the lower one, put wire nuts on the wires from the outlet, leave them in the box with the switches, and then put on the face plate? Or is that not safe? If it's not, then my plan is to move the upper switch down and have the two switches and the outlet in a row, even if the outlet really won't get any use. Unless there are other options?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cap the wires, and cover the box with a blank faceplate.  There's no problem with that, as long as the twist-on wire connectors are the correct size for a single wire.

Comment: And there is also nothing to stop you from cutting out the existing boxes and putting in new ones exactly where you want. Just remember that all wire ends (including those in a wire nut or attached to a device (outlet, switch)) must not be dry walled over.

Comment: So it would be okay to have the wire ends from the outlet we no longer want in a box with the two switches we do want in a two gang box, or would that be unsafe?

Comment: @user53133 -- that is A-OK as long as you don't overstuff the box.